# Learning ruby for loop

Tags: ruby

Hi I'm going through this loop and sending a list of words `lines` and a string `str` to match it. For some reason it's not printing `eureka` though:

```
def search_array(str, lines)
    count = 0
    lines.each do |i|
        count +=1
        if str == i
            puts 'eureka'
        end
    end
end

FILE_LOC = "words.txt"
lines = File.readlines(FILE_LOC)
word = "hello"

search_array(word, lines)
```

Comment: as I said: a list (also known as an array) of words `lines` and a string `str`

Comment: I understand that. Post full runnable code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Just curious, if you make the first item in the array match the string, does it work then?

Comment: @PhillipKregg No it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Theres no compile problem - it just doesn't print anything

Comment: Who said about compile problem? There's a problem with your input values.

Comment: I'm using lines = File.readlines("text.txt") and when i call lines[0] it works.

Comment: cfarm54 have you seen @SimonMayers answer?

Comment: This whole thing could be replaced with a single line: `puts "Eureka" if lines.include? word`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class Looper


  def search_array(str, lines)
    count = 0
    lines.each do |i|
        count +=1
        if str == i 
            puts 'eureka'
        end
    end
  end

end

looper = Looper.new

looper.search_array('fish', ['taco', 'horse', 'fish'])
```

I'm not sure how you are running your program, but you can just copy and paste this into a text editor and save it as "LooperTest.rb".  Then open your terminal and change directories to the path with this file in it and run it like this: `ruby LooperTest.rb`

Comment: So I'm currently trying to read in the file like this:
`loop = Looper.new`

`FILE_LOC = "words.txt"`
`lines = File.readlines(FILE_LOC)`

`word = "hello"`
`loop.search_array(word, lines)`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I do:

```
lines = ["a", "b", "c"]

search_array("b", lines)
```

Are you getting lines from a file, or some other kind of input? If so, are they ending in newline characters? If so, try:

```
if str == i.chomp
```

Comment: Exactly, what do you see if you do `p lines`?